# Extract Images from JSON Object

Tags: android, json

I am fetching the most popular movies from an api, and I am trying to get the poster images for each movie. To do so I need to extract the **poster_path** parameter from the json string.

This is my code to extract information from the JSON string:

```
final String OWM_RESULTS = "results";
final String OWM_POSTERPATH = "poster_path";

String aux;

// movieJSONstr is the string with the full http request
JSONObject movieJson = new JSONObject(movieJSONstr);
JSONArray movieArray = movieJson.getJSONArray(OWM_RESULTS);

for(int i = 0; i < movieArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject movieObj = movieArray.getJSONObject(i);
    aux = movieObj.getString(OWM_POSTERPATH);
    Log.v("AUX: ", aux);
}
```

The JSON string looks something like this:

```
{
"page":1,
"results":[
  {
     "adult":false,
     "backdrop_path":"/tbhdm8UJAb4ViCTsulYFL3lxMCd.jpg",
     "genre_ids":[
        53,
        28,
        12
     ],
     "id":76341,
     "original_language":"en",
     "original_title":"Mad Max: Fury Road",
     "overview":"An apocalyptic story set in the furthest reaches of our planet, in a stark desert landscape where humanity is broken, and most everyone is crazed fighting for the necessities of life. Within this world exist two rebels on the run who just might be able to restore order. There's Max, a man of action and a man of few words, who seeks peace of mind following the loss of his wife and child in the aftermath of the chaos. And Furiosa, a woman of action and a woman who believes her path to survival may be achieved if she can make it across the desert back to her childhood homeland.",
     "release_date":"2015-05-15",
     "poster_path":"/kqjL17yufvn9OVLyXYpvtyrFfak.jpg",
     "popularity":46.603256,
     "title":"Mad Max: Fury Road",
     "video":false,
     "vote_average":7.6,
     "vote_count":2296
  }]
}
```

Assuming that the JSONObject does indeed have the images, how can I extract them and convert them into something I can manipulate like an instance of Drawable?

Comment: 1. send the imageurl as string then download from it. 2. Download image from url. There are some libraries which can help you if you get the url. Try `Picasso`.

Comment: check this http://square.github.io/picasso/ all you need is a url

Comment: The Json string already has the image right? So proper coding should use that "functionality" imo... I wanted to use just one http request if it was possible.

Comment: The json should contain the **imageurl**. i.e like `http://xxx/xxx/xxx.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are (in general) 2 ways to pass images through JSON.
First and in my opinion not the best one is put raw image data into JSON object. You can encode image with base64, and put it as a string into the object, then decode base64 and decode raw data with `BitmapFactory` class.

The second and better way is passing image as URL and it seems that Json you presented is using this method:

```
"poster_path":"/kqjL17yufvn9OVLyXYpvtyrFfak.jpg"
```

The most raw solution for this problem is presented akhil batlawala's answer. For real world applications you probably should look for some image library like Picasso with usage like:

```
Picasso picasso = new Picasso();
picasso.load(url).fit().into(myImageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) poplayout.findViewById(R.id.popupimg);
String serverpath = "yourimage path on server";
URL imageURL;

try {
    imageURL = new URL(serverpath +""+ aux);
    Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURL.openStream());
    img.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You probably should add a note, that this code must be run with some non - UI thread. For example using AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code,

```
String response = "Your string";
         try {
            JSONObject jObject=new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray jArray=jObject.getJSONArray("results");
            JSONObject obj=jArray.getJSONObject(0);
            String poster_path=obj.getString("poster_path");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

That's it